# Limit Data Selections in Python Eve rest api framework

Tags: python, rest, eve

I want to return the first 100 rows from api endpoint like

```
localhost/products?limit=100

localhost/products?aggregate={"$limit": 100}
```

Is it possible to do with Eve?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
localhost/products?max_results=100
```

If you prefer, you can switch from `max_results` to `limit` with `QUERY_MAX_RESULTS = 'limit'` in your settings. Also, take care of the other useful pagination settings:

```
PAGINATION_LIMIT
Maximum value allowed for QUERY_MAX_RESULTS query parameter. Values exceeding the limit will be silently replaced with this value. You want to aim for a reasonable compromise between performance and transfer size. Defaults to 50.

PAGINATION_DEFAULT
Default value for QUERY_MAX_RESULTS. Defaults to 25.

OPTIMIZE_PAGINATION_FOR_SPEED
Set this to True to improve pagination performance. When optimization is active no count operation, which can be slow on large collections, is performed on the database. This does have a few consequences. Firstly, no document count is returned. Secondly, HATEOAS is less accurate: no last page link is available, and next page link is always included, even on last page. On big collections, switching this feature on can greatly improve performance. Defaults to False (slower performance; document count included; accurate HATEOAS).

QUERY_MAX_RESULTS
Key for the max results query parameter. Defaults to max_results.
```

There are more settings available, just check the docs.

Comment: With max_results you are limiting only items per page not full results set.

Comment: After some considerations I believe such functionality is redundant as I requested.